# How can I run my applescript at intervals

Tags: macos, applescript, plist, automator, launchd

I've made a script that each day it gets the local time, and then makes an alias of a folder specified by me through code on the desktop. At the beginning, it asks for what day it is (via a list). It doesn't work because even if I use launchd to run it every 5 minutes, it will ask me for the list. Is there a way to get the variable stored every day, and then just make it do the rest of the work throughout the day?

I've actually combined AppleScript and Automator to make it function, so I need to make the Automator run and not the AppleScript.

My PLIST Code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>  
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>wallpaper.restart</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>PATH:TO:FILE</string> 
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>1</integer>

       </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I would appreciate any pointers for me to get started, or anything that could help.

Thanks

Comment: As already mentioned in your related question, this code runs the script on 1 pm every day (and always when the computer is started up due to the `RunAtLoad` key) but not interval based. To save states do it on the AppleScript/Automator side either in a property, using user defaults or the `load/store script` pattern. And what's `keepAlive` for?

Comment: @vadian Sorry for the late response - and thank you for the quick response ;)   Yes you are right, and I by mistake copied the wrong code. In my new code, I have the new update.

Comment: Once again: Do you know what `keepAlive` actually does?

Comment: @vadian - It means keep the script alive/running while the user is using the computer/logged on. Right?

Comment: `keepAlive` affects only UNIX processes with a runloop. A script is not a process so `keepAlive` has no effect at all.

Comment: @vadian Sorry.. then I did not know.

Answer (score 0):

To run a script at some interval, you'd use a .plist that looks something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.myScript</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/myScript/myScript.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>
    <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>600</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Change the 600 to whatever number of seconds you'd like it to run at, for example 300 for every 5 minutes.

To write data to a .plist file so you can access it at any time, you would use something like this...

```
do shell script "defaults write com.mycompany.myApp MyInfo '" & theInfo & "'"
```

To then read the information you'd use code like this...

```
set myPref to do shell script "defaults read com.mycompany.myApp MyInfo"
```

Lastly, I'm not sure you need a "list", you can get the date using a script similar to this...

```
do shell script "date \"+%Y-%m-%d\""
```

The format that I've chosen in this example is 2016-06-01, but you can change the format information to whatever you'd like by changing the string after the date command. See the manual page for date for more information or look [here](http://ss64.com/bash/date.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my specification is Day 1, Day 2 etc. to Day 6. Also, I'm not sure but the script you provided, would it store a variable for at most one day? Could we try running it as a server (or would that do nothing?)

Comment: @Dev The line `set myPref to do shell script "defaults read com.mycompany.myApp MyInfo"` will write the data to a .plist file that will live as long as the file exists (the file is written to your preference folder). I'm not sure what your "Day 1" and "Day 2" refer to, but you can use the command "date" as i suggested to get the day of the week, week of the year or many other options. Depending on your use case, it may still be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Just to clarify again, Day 1 Day 2 Day 3 are basically names I've set up. It goes up to Day 6. The reason I can't use 'date'  is because it isn't really something a system would recognize, something made up by me. Please don't get confused with Day 1 Day 2 and Monday Tuesday because they are completely different things.  Its almost like having names out of the wild - 'bananas, apples, oranges'. These are organized words, but not something applescript would know vs. 'June 2, 2016 or 12:33:04PM etc.'.

Comment: @Dev Makes sense. I was just wondering if you'd be able to use date and your "random words" to know when to change from "Day 1" to "Day 2", that sort of thing.

Comment: How it works is, If Tomorrow (June 6) is a Day 1, then Friday will become Day 5, and the next Monday will become Day 6. So it is a repeating cycle from Mon - Fri. I think it would be hard to integrate with date, but maybe we could give it a try.  @ThrowBackDewd